# I have a problem with Azure AD - SAML 2.0 configuration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0

I need help with configuring the Identifier(Entity ID) and Reply Url of my configuration in Azure for Active Directory SAML 2.0, I don't know how to configure them

I have tried to set them some value but I got this message:

> AADSTS750054: SAMLRequest or SAMLResponse must be present as query
> string parameters in HTTP requests for SAML Redirect binding.

Any ideas on how to make it works?

Comment: Have you got the client metadata? You can get them from there.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong URL here. For IDP initiated URL please find the "`User Access URL`" from the ***Azure AD Application Properties tab.*** Then you can use that URL in the browser and it will do the SSO. Also alternatively the user can log in to Access Panel https://myapps.microsoft.com and then click on the application tile to perform the SSO. In the Azure Portal got to Azure `Active Directory -> Enterprise Apps -> Search your app -> Click on the app -> Properties page -> User Access URL`

Answer (score 0):

How to enable Azure AD SAML authentication depends on the SAML library you're using. Generally, the entityID and Reply URL are APP ID URI and Reply URL of your registered application in AAD. After you configured the library correctly, it will automatically help generate SAMLRequest for you.

Here is an configuration example of using [Sustainsys.Saml2](https://saml2.sustainsys.com/en/2.0/index.html) library:

```
  <!--entityId is APP ID URI of your registered application in AAD; Return URL is Reply URL-->
  <sustainsys.saml2 entityId="https://www.contoso.org/checkresourceapp"  

                    returnUrl="http://localhost:54664/"

                    >
    <nameIdPolicy allowCreate="true" format="Persistent"/>
    <identityProviders>
      <add entityId="https://sts.windows.net/<your tenant id>/"
          metadataLocation="https://login.microsoftonline.com/<your tenant id>/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml"
          loadMetadata = "true"
          allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true"
          signOnUrl="https://login.microsoftonline.com/<your tenant id>"
          binding="HttpRedirect">     
      </add>

    </identityProviders>
    <federations>
      <add metadataLocation="https://login.microsoftonline.com/<your tenant id>/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml" allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse = "false" />
    </federations>
  </sustainsys.saml2>
```

Regarding complete interpretation, please refer to https://saml2.sustainsys.com/en/2.0/configuration.html